# Is it possible to have a bash script Jenkins job report Red, Amber, and Green?

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have a couple of bash scripts running on Jenkins which return `0` and `1` exit codes depending on their outcome and the Jenkins job shows as green and red, respectively.

We have other Jenkins jobs which sometimes go amber. What exit code do I need to return to get that from a bash script?

Answer (score 1):

The "Execute Shell" build step has an Advanced button.
Click on it and you can enter the exit code that Jenkins will interpret as "unstable".